# number of words in language $L \subset \Sigma$

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, regular-expressions

I had my lecture today about decidable languages and as I am reviewing the material I have from the university, I got quite confused about the following definition:

$\emptyset$ doesn't contain any words and is called the empty set. $\Sigma^*$ contains all possible languages from $\Sigma$, and $\Sigma$ **contains all words of length 1**.

Does this mean if I define a Language $L \subset \Sigma$, $L$ is the set of all Languages of length 1?

Specifically, if $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$, then the length $L$ is 2?

Comment: $\Sigma$ means the two words $0,1$, $\Sigma^2$ means the four words $00,01,10,11$, etc. $\Sigma^* = \Sigma \cup \Sigma^2 \cup \Sigma^3 \cup...$.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by the length of a language. Also, if $L \in \Sigma$ then either $L=0$ or $L=1$. Perhaps you mean $L \subset \Sigma$?

Comment: @copper.hat yes I meant $\subset$, edited the question. Thank you for your first comment, this clears the issue :)